# Spring boot (Maven) and GCP - Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: spring, maven, google-cloud-sql, web-development-server

I'm trying to connect my google cloud database to my spring project. Whenever I try to run my spring project, I get the following error.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-04 22:50:46.057 ERROR 488 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Below is my `pom.xml` and `application.properties`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projectname</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Add Spring Cloud GCP Dependency BOM -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
# database = postgresql
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=<the google cloud instance ID>
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=<the connection name>
spring.datasource.username=<username of a user account I added to GCP>
spring.datasource.password=<password of the user account I added to GCP>

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

The rest of my spring project has not been altered in any way at all. `pom.xml` and `application.properties` under `src\main\resources` are the only two files that have been changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: In my `pom.xml` I've changed the groupId to `org.springframework.cloud` from `com.google.cloud` which has fixed that issue.

But the issue with my application.properties still exists.

Comment: I updated my `pom.xml` and now I'm not getting any warnings. But the app still won't start.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your `pom.xml` and didn't have any error.

If you are using Intellij IDEA, *try*:

- Invalidate cache & restart may help ( File > Invalidate caches....),
- Check all options and then click invalidate and restart.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try without the IDE to make sure whether it is problem related to maven repository. Inside the project folder, run this command and see if all dependencies are successfully resolved:

```sh
./mvnw dependency:resolve
```

Comment: Unfortunately invalidating caches & restarting didn't work. When I ran  `mvnw dependency:resolve` I got the message "\Year was unexpected at this time". The dependency issues in my `pom.xml` were not solved. What should I do next?

Comment: My `pom.xml` issues were fixed when I changed the groupId to `org.springframework.cloud` from `com.google.cloud` but my application.properties is still not working.

Comment: I don't think you should change the group ID since they may have different dependencies hierarchy. Changing group ID may lead to other unexpected error

Answer (score -1):

By default Spring Boot auto-configuration tries to auto configure the beans based on the dependencies added to the pom.xml file of the application. Since the application usually has the JPA(Java Persistence API) dependency in the pom.xml file, Spring Boot tries to automatically configure a JPA DataSource. The JPA DataSource bean requires a database driver to connect to a database. When the Spring DataSource information is not given in the application.properties file, which is needed to auto configure, it gives this error.

To mitigate the error please use the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property in `application.properties` file as follows -

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```